# Inverse Standardization of predicted values

Tags: pandas, tensorflow, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I've dataset with two columns. At first I've split the data into train, val and test and after that I've standardized all the data (train, val and test).

```
train_mean = train_data.mean()
train_std = train_data.std()

train_df = (train_data - train_mean) / train_std
val_df = (val_data - train_mean) / train_std
test_df = (test_data - train_mean) / train_std
```

After that I've split the train_df and val_df into X_train, X_test and y_train, y_test respectively for model training.

```
time_step = 288 
X_train, y_train = create_dataset(train_df, time_step)
X_val, y_val = create_dataset(val_df, time_step)
```

After and training the model I've predict the values but when I tried to inverse the predicted values it gives me error.

```
test_predict=multi_step_dense.predict(X_val)
```

**Inverse the predicted values:**

```
inverse_data = (df * data_std) + data_mean
```

**The error which I'm facing**

```
ValueError: Length of values (14604) does not match length of index (2)
```

Answer (score 0):

difficult to follow without the possibility of replicating the issue. however, shouldn't it be `(test_predict * data_std) + data_mean`